# jQuery not loading the source aspx page

Tags: java, asp.net, jquery

Hi i have iframe tag in pop up window.
in iframe am loading another page.
if am used below code am unable to load the spurce page.

```
enter code here<iframe id="Iframe1" width="802" height="500">
          <script type="text/javascript">
              $(function () {
                  document.getElementById("testframe").src = "SelectMembers.aspx";

              });
          </script>       

        </iframe>
```

or

if am used below code am getting this error.
'__pendingCallbacks[...].async' is null or not an object: callback async[i]...FIX :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not put the javascript `between` iframe tags. Add javascript in `head` of just before `closing` body tag. Also make sure that you have SelectMembers.aspx in the same folder you have the current page.

*html*

```
<iframe id="Iframe1" width="802" height="500"> </iframe>
```

*Javacript before body closing tag*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          document.getElementById("testframe").src = "SelectMembers.aspx";

      });
</script>       
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
            document.getElementById("Iframe1").src = "/SelectMembers.aspx";

          });​
      </script>   

    <iframe id="Iframe1" width="802" height="500">


    </iframe>
```